# compile program with set runtime environment?

Tags: c, compilation, environment

I am trying to compile a program which, when run, will be run in a predefined environment in c.

More specifically, I am looking to somehow include `LD_PRELOAD=./lib.so` so that when I run `./program` it will run as if I had used the command `LD_PRELOAD=./lib.so ./program`

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: And a launcher script is out of the question?

Comment: How about linking your program against `lib.so` and adding `.` to the `rpath`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean.  I have to preload the shared library because I'm using it to overwrite an already defined function.

Comment: First I think you meant `LD_PRELOAD` and not `LS_PRELOAD`. Second why not just put this in a script?

Answer (score 0):

Make the program set `LS_PRELOAD` and then run itself if `LS_PRELOAD` isn't set. Use `execv()` for that.

Comment: The problem is that I can't touch the program that is being run

Comment: @MichaelRizzo Then make a _second_ program which uses `execv` to call the real program with the correct environment.